# Rails does not specify the javascript file with an error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't understand how anyone in the entire world is supposed to understand what javascript file rails is talking about here.

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:81:5: unexpected if
Extracted source (around line #17):
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true, defer: defer ? defer : false
```

Comment: can you describe you prblem in details.

Comment: you have taken `:defer` instead of `defer` in your terniary operation success condition. that gives you the error.

Comment: That does not answer my initial question, which is which file contains the error? The answer was one of my javascript files, I am wondering which file, not this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-trac ': true, defer: defer ? defer : false
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation?

Comment: He has used symbol instead of variable in ternary condition.

Comment: That does not answer my initial question, which is which file contains the error? The answer was one of my javascript files, I am wondering which file, not this line of code.